# Winsock overlapped IO and message parsing

Tags: c++, overlap, winsock2

I have to implement a (client) socket which requires high throughput (> 800Mbps) and low latency running on Windows 7 server. Overlapped IO seems the way to go for high performance.

Read some documentation on the subject, as far as I can see the advantage of overlapped I/O is that you pass some structures with buffer to the OS and you are notified when they are filled.

No I am wondering what the common ways are to combine this with a packet based protocol (length delimited packets, header contains size of datablock)
Of course I can just read arbitrary chunks of data and copy the required number of bytes into a message struture. This means an additional copy action.

Second option might be passing the message structure as a buffer with the header size, after getting it back pass the same structure again to read the requested number of databytes. In this case the first chunk read is small, but the data is saved into the message structure, and while the data block read is pending the read of the next header block can be initialized.

Any experiences or ideas how to handle length delimited packets the most efficient ?

Thanks,

Comment: I would explore a number of things, but if performance is at the very top of your wish-list, i'd consider IOCP to be almost-mandetory if you really want scalable performance. Anything else you come up with should be put on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [scatter/gather I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you know the packet sizes.

Comment: Thanks...I will do. The packet size is dependent on the header and might vary per packet.

Comment: I wondered about that.  Even so, if you have a reasonable max size you might get efficiency gains from this.